# Python - BPIPE API python SDK installation error

Tags: python

I'm getting this error message when trying to install BPIPE API python SDK

command

```
pip3 install --index-url=https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple blpapi
```

error message

```
    DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
Looking in indexes: https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple
Collecting blpapi
  Using cached https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple/blpapi/blpapi-3.18.3.tar.gz (304 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [3 lines of output]
      Looking in indexes: https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=40.8.0 (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=40.8.0
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: Try updating setuptools `pip install --upgrade setuptools` - and perhaps pip itself `pip install --upgrade pip`. You need a version > 40.8.0

Comment: I already update setuptools & pip. just updated the error message

Comment: It looks to me like it's trying to update setuptools from https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple for some reason. I don't get an error on linux installing in a venv, looks like you're on MacOS and I've had similar issues with python on macos

Comment: Maybe try installing in a virtualenv? `pythons3 -m venv .venv` creates a new environment in folder `.venv`

Comment: Then `source .venv/bin/activate` then `pip install --update pip` and `pip install --index-url=https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple blpapi
`

Comment: already tried, still not working